# Having problem in back propagation part for dimension

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I was trying to build a neural network with single hidden layer from scratch. In back propagation part some problems have raised. 
For calculating gradient of loss function with respect to weight in layer-1 the equation becomes:

$$ \frac{dL}{dW1} = \frac{dL}{dA1}*\frac{dA1}{dZ1}*\frac{dZ1}{dW1}$$
where,

$$ \frac{dL}{dA1} = \frac{dL}{dA2}*\frac{dA2}{dZ2}*\frac{dZ2}{dA1}$$

Should I calculate it with *np.dot()* or *np.multiply()*?

I was trying to do it with *np.dot()* and having problem with dimension. dL/dW1 dimenion doesn't fit when I go to update W1.

Here is my code and pardon me as it is little bit messy in back propagation part.

https://gist.github.com/ipritom/30fcad0c74ab59e5b31e1daac1c1d1e7